# regular expression php how to add empty string in it

Tags: php, regex

i have this regular expression in php:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([1-9]|1[012])(,([1-9]|1[012]))*$/', $value))
```

and i want this condition to not run when the $value is just an empty string '' but it runs on empty string please help

Comment: `if ($value!= '')`?

Comment: Ahmed's advice is equivalent to `if ($value)`.  Both are "loose comparisons".  https://3v4l.org/TfY3i

Comment: Alternatively, you could just as `(` and `)?` to make the expression between `^` and `$` optional. [`/^([1-9]|1[012](,([1-9]|1[012]))*)?$/`](https://3v4l.org/TE9bX) but I prefer simply doing `if ($value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the empty string separately.

```
if ($value != '' && !preg_match('/^([1-9]|1[012])(,([1-9]|1[012]))*$/', $value))
```

Comment: yeah i tried but somehow i messed up && and wrote || instead of &&. thank you that will work.